# Incrementing the CSS padding-top property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS defined for a `div`

```
#myDiv
{
  padding-top: 20px,
  padding-bottom: 30px
}
```

In a JS function, I would like to increment the value of `padding-top` by 10px

```
function DoStuff()
{
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  //Increment by 10px. Which property to use and how? something like..
  //myDiv.style.paddingTop += 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.style` property can only read *inline* styles defined on an element. It cannot read styles defined in stylesheets.

You need a library to get the value, or use something like (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395341/get-element-stylesheet-style-in-javascript)):

```
function getStyle(elem, name) {
    // J/S Pro Techniques p136
    if (elem.style[name]) {
        return elem.style[name];
    } else if (elem.currentStyle) {
        return elem.currentStyle[name];
    }
    else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        name = name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1");
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        s = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, "");
        return s && s.getPropertyValue(name);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
    padding = getStyle(element, 'paddingTop'); // eg "10px"

element.style.paddingTop = parseInt(padding, 10) + 10 + 'px';
```

References:

- [`.style` and inline vs stylesheet styles](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)
- [`getStyle` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395341/get-element-stylesheet-style-in-javascript)
- [radix (2nd) parameter to `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using jquery to do this sort of thing, as most other solutions won't be very cross browser compatible and you'll spend days pulling your hair out over it.

```
function Dostuff()
{
    var currentPadding =  $('#myDiv').css('padding-top');
    $('#myDiv').css('padding-top', currentPadding + 1);
}
```

See jquery.com for more.

Comment: yeah but I think jQuery is the defacto and the best IMO.

Comment: try to avoid global vars (currentPadding) by using the var keyword to scope it

Comment: actually, this doesn't seem to be working for me.  `currentPadding + 1` is coming up with stuff like `"25px1"`

Comment: try `var currentPadding =  parseInt($('#myDiv').css('padding-top'));`

Comment: Or, if padding can possibly be a floating point number due to using `em`'s or something, use `parseFloat()`