# Get html source using javascript including style

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the html source of a website including all the styles of the elements set by the css.  So basically the rendered html of the page, such that if an element is hidden it has `style = display:none`

When using the functions below style attributes added by the css are not included in the string.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
```

or

```
inDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Is there a way to include the css attributes?

Thanks,
James

Comment: I'm actually passing the html string back to java so iframes aren't an option

Comment: Sorry, actually posted an answer and then checked this.. This may be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781410/jquery-how-to-get-all-styles-css-defined-within-internal-external-document-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think jQuery is necessary for fetching the HTML Source. 
Just use

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

This will include the CSS attributes as well.

Comment: Will it include computed styles also?

Comment: Sorry, actually posted an answer and then checked this.. This may be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781410/jquery-how-to-get-all-styles-css-defined-within-internal-external-document-w

Answer (score 1):

This will help you [jQuery CSS plugin that returns computed style of element to pseudo clone that element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el)

Also check the jQuery clone function mentioned here http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: So I could run that as I parse the elements and add them to a string?  Then return the string.

Comment: >>add them to a string
Not sure. But you can add them to an object, because clone() returns a jQuery object.