# Get ALL DEFINED( in stylesheet/inline ) css styles of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to get all css styles of an element that are **defined** in external stylesheet ( style.css ? ) or in **HTML** ( inline css ).

All solutions i found tend to return [object] so user can apply to another Element.

The following code prints all elements not just those that are defined.

```
$(this).css("cssText");
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: SO user can change styles from GUI. Using .css("cssText") will generate loads of input boxes and will indeed frustrate the end user.

Comment: Possible answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781410/jquery-how-to-get-all-styles-css-defined-within-internal-external-document-w)?

Comment: i get " Type Error: "

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
    $("div").each(function(){       
        /* FROM EXTERNAL CSS STYLESHEET */    
        var currentStyle = this.currentStyle
        var opacityStyle = currentStyle.opacity /* get opacity for example */
    })
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that styles vary from element to element. I dont know what elements are defined in external stylesheet for element, say, X.