# How to get the ultimate, final calculated style value on an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does one get the ultimate, final, after-inheritance style value for an HTML element in JavaScript? I already know that [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) only gets the inline styles, and that [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) only does elementary transformations on the inline styles (it doesn't appear to be inheriting anything from the style sheets). How do I get the inherited style values?

I'd prefer not to use jQuery (since I know that a pure JavaScript solution is possible, though jQuery is already in use in my application). I don't know what the stylesheet configuration is ahead of time because the sheets are being compiled together with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

My specific case is that I'm trying to get a business-defined color from the stylesheet for a canvas-based drawing task, and the colors are defined in the CSS. I'm currently trying to use code like the following to extract my entities.

```
var testElement = document.createElement("span");
var entity_type_color_table = {};
function getEntityTypeColor(entity_type) {
    if (!entity_type_color_table[entity_type]) {
        testElement.className = entity_type + "-color";
        entity_type_color_table[entity_type] = 
            document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(testElement, null)
            .getPropertyValue("color");
    }         
    return entity_type_color_table[entity_type];     
}
```

Comment: i think you might just want to use jQuery to solve this. by using .css(). Reason being that jQuery already takes care of alot of browser inconsistencies.

Comment: I noticed you're using `document.createElement('span');`. When I replace that with a proper DOM node (see: http://jsfiddle.net/12dsjur3/) it returns the color properly. Could that be the reason why you aren't seeing any values from `getComputedStyle`?

Comment: You know you could just read the specific style sheet's rules using document.styleSheets[0].cssRules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing any of the stylesheet styles because you haven't attached your test element to the document.  After creating your `testElement`, doing:

```
document.body.appendChild(testElement);
```

Should suffice.

Alternatively, if having the test element attached permanently is a problem, you could attach and detach it in your test function:

```
if (!entity_type_color_table[entity_type]) {
    testElement.className = entity_type + "-color";
    document.body.appendChild(testElement);
    entity_type_color_table[entity_type] = 
        document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(testElement, null)
        .getPropertyValue("color");
    testElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: Precisely what I was thinking in my comment.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Put it on the DOM somewhere, it works like a charm. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

This question here may help: [jQuery - How to get all styles/css (defined within internal/external document) with HTML of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781410/jquery-how-to-get-all-styles-css-defined-within-internal-external-document-w) as well as [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

You can get external and inline styles by using document.styleSheets and as @Puzzle84 noted, jquery's .css()