# Printing the style of selected dom it comes out as dictionary with values " " even when i have specified it with the style tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

my style tag has

```
 <style>
        #armsblue{
            position:absolute;
            left:0.33vw;
            top:-0.3vw;
            z-index: -1; 
        }
        
</style>
```

the body tag has :

```
<img src="E:\graphics\torsoblue.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="80%" id="torsoblue">
            <img src="E:\graphics\armsblue.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="80%" id="armsblue">
```

the javascript that prints the img dom with armsblue id:

```
torsos=document.querySelectorAll("#torsoblue,");
console.log(torsos[0].style);
```

the output comes out as on console :

```
CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
```

when u expand this and check the dictionary has position: "" , zIndex: "" and so on even when i put these values inside the  tag.

Comment: Yes, inline style object of the element is not the same as CSS defined in a stylesheet. Notice also, that your script "_prints the img dom with __torsoblue__ id_".

Comment: Getting all the CSS applied to an element is not a trivial task, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781410/jquery-how-to-get-all-styles-css-defined-within-internal-external-document-w).

Comment: you can retrieve the computed (applied) style with `getComputedStyle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want to access CSS properties from stylesheet which require using `window.getComputedStyle` otherwise you could use `HTMLElement.style` if those properties were used inline like in `#torsoblue` example.

```js
  const torsos = document.querySelectorAll('#torsoblue');
  console.log(torsos[0].style.position);
  console.log(torsos[0].style.left);
  console.log(torsos[0].style.top);
  console.log(torsos[0].style.zIndex);

  const armsblueEl = document.getElementById('armsblue');
  const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(armsblueEl);
  console.log(computedStyle.position);
  console.log(computedStyle.left);
  console.log(computedStyle.top);
  console.log(computedStyle.zIndex);
```

```css
  #armsblue {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.33vw;
    top: -0.3vw;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

```html
<img src="#" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="80%" id="torsoblue"
     style="position: relative;left: 0.66vw;top:-0.6vw;z-index: -2">

<img src="#" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="80%" id="armsblue">
```