# How to remove all inherited and computed styles from an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

The page has the following CSS:

```
input[type=text]
{
    display: inline; padding: 7px; background-color: #f6f6f6; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: 1px; border: 1px solid #aac7d1; 
    /* lots of other styles here... */
}
```

I have many text-input elements and the following:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
```

And I try to apply different styles to this individual textbox (txt1) via jQuery:

```
$('#txt1').removeClass().removeAttr('style').css({
    'background-color': '#ff0000',
    //lots of other styles here...
});
```

But those styles that come from the style-sheet cannot be removed from the element this way. The css rule, `input[type=text]` is not a custom class so `removeClass()` does not work here, if I'm right.

What I want to do is; to completely remove all styles ever applied to the element `txt1`. Is there a certain way to do this other than getting the list of all computed styles and setting them empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a certain way to do this

There is no way to stop rules applying to an element if the selector matches.

You can either

- set every property you want to have a specific value (with a suitably specific selector and `!important`
- move the element to a different document (which could then be loaded with, for example, an iframe).
- remove the rule (and thus cause it to not apply to *any* element)
- change the selector on the ruleset (so it doesn't match the element any more, you have to be careful to make sure it still selects elements you care about)

> other than getting the list of all computed styles and setting them empty?

That wouldn't work. Most properties won't accept a blank value, so the rule would be invalid and ignored (thus causing the previous rule to apply again).

Comment: I think you're right. I can reset all computed styles, within a loop but it's not too logical.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity, all selectors has specificity value. So, if you write such css rule: `#txt1 {}`, you can reset all unnecessary values.

Comment: I think that we need to clarify this situation.

So, if you have such rule: `input[type=text] { background-color: #f6f6f6; }` and want to overload background-color for your item, you should use rule `#txt1 { background-color: #ff0000; }`