# How to set all computed styles as literal styles on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

This question is similar (I think) to this question on SO: [How to move all computed CSS styles from one element and apply them to a different element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808400/how-to-move-all-computed-css-styles-from-one-element-and-apply-them-to-a-differe)

What I want to do is find all styles that have been applied by way of css sheets and set the explicitly (as in using a style= attribute) on the element. The reason I want to do this is so that MS Word (2010) will pick up the styling if I open it there

Here's my code

```
var $this = $(this);
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(this, null);
$this.css(styles);
```

I also tried with

```
var styles = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this, null);
```

When I put a try catch around the last line ($this.css(styles), I am getting an error message "invalid calling object". I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: A [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) is not a plain object as expected by jQuerys [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) method.

Comment: Could you please specify a reason to do it?

Comment: @KoshVery I have added my reason in the question body. It's so that the style shows up in MS Word 2010

Comment: @Andreas understood. So if you can't apply a CSSStyleDeclaration like I am trying, does this make the answer to the "similar" question I referenced incorrect?

Comment: @KoshVery to clarify: classes set on paragraphs are showing up in MS Word. But classes on spans are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the following snippet does what you want, though I don't think it's what you needed. MS Word is NOT a browser, I'm not sure if it supports all the styles or if jQuery works there...

```js
var $this = $('b');
var styles = window.getComputedStyle($this[0]);

$this.css(
  Object.values(styles).reduce(
    (a, e) => 0*(a[e] = styles[e]) || a, {}
  )
)

console.log(`style="${$this.attr('style')}"`)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>I have styles</b>
```

Comment: Actually, you are right about "what I need". Stepped away and took lunch, and I realized that the problem could very well be with my CSS formatting... And this is what it is / was! Thank you though for answering the question I asked

Comment: @ControlAltDel, happy to help!