# Extract CSS from an element with javascript

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to build sort of an Applet that you can run into any page and by selecting a element you extract it's css attributes?

Imagine like firebug allows you to select the div you want to see the code, but instead you select for example a button and get the CSS of it in a selectable field you can copy and paste.

Comment: You mean, like firebug?  https://getfirebug.com/css

Comment: This should be easy to implement. You'd need a mouseClickListener. And then you can extract the Style from the selected element using a .style or a .css. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968593/how-to-set-multiple-css-style-properties-in-javascript
and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395341/get-element-stylesheet-style-in-javascript
and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thanks who tried to help with this question.

After thinking about what I was asking and wanting to do is pretty much what we already can find on the built in browser web developer tools such as chrome or firefox.

There's no point in reinventing the wheel so the answer would be, yes it's possible to do so with javascript but it's not necessary because we already can find tools to achieve the same result which would be examining the html and css and being able to copy/extract it from the source.

Thanks for your time and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the CSSStyleDeclaration object via [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)

```
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('foo'), null);
for (style in styles) {
    if (styles.hasOwnProperty(style)) {
        console.log(style, styles[style]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Firebug bug Chrome's Developer Tools gives you CSS that you can copy, paste and edit. It also shows a breakdown of which files, internal styles or inlines the styles are coming from, and the final cascaded "Computed Style."

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Yes it does, even firefox developer bar has a lot of cool features. I was thinking about something you can add to your bookmark as an aplet and then you can simply click on a element on the page you are and extract that bit of html and its css style.