# Cant find opacity on div?

Tags: javascript, opacity, jsfiddle

In my code I dont find the opacity for the div "box", if I call the function toggle it shows zero.

Why doesnt it shows 2 as it should because opacity is 1 and multiplied with 2.

Here is my code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxRGB/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #box {
            background-color:blue;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            opacity:1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    <script>
        var faded = false;
        var current = document.getElementById("box").style.opacity *2;
        var toggle = function() {
            document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = current;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

By accessing the `style` property, you only get the inline styles of the element. Your styles are defined using a stylesheet. What you need to use is [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle). Do note about its [compatibility here](http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle).

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxRGB/3/

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function toggle() {
    var styles = window.getComputedStyle(box, null);
    var opacity = styles.getPropertyValue('opacity');
    box.innerHTML = opacity * 2;
}
```

To make it more robust, [you can do what this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395341/575527). You can check for the style in the `style` property, and when it doesn't exist there, check the stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var current = document.getElementById("box");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(current);
var opacity = style.getPropertyValue('opacity') * 2;
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = opacity;
```

If you have inline style or add style through javascript you can use `.style` but adding it through css use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.getComputedStyle)

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/ZxRGB/1/