# How to get the specified style from CSS as opposed to the computed style from the element?

Tags: jquery, css

I know similar questions have been asked, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395341/get-element-stylesheet-style-in-javascript), but I've not been able to find a solution that works.

Can someone suggest how I could fetch the value of the width attribute from the CSS class so I can write it to the div?

I want to fetch the actual value set in the class, even if the actual element has been stretched further due to content.

Happy to do this with jQuery if possible.

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = 'value of CSS width';
```

```css
#myDiv {
    width: 177px; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking to get the css value that's in effect on the div, so do you care if there's multiple styles that apply but are getting overridden?

Comment: I want to fetch the actual value set in the class, even if the actual element has been stretched further due to content.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395341/get-element-stylesheet-style-in-javascript) doesn't answer your question, but some of the approaches might help you get the style specified instead of the computed style

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm just going to hardcode in a number instead of trying to fetch it from the class. I'm not a big fan of these type of hacks.

Answer (score 0):

This article from the jQuery documentation may help you.  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Try:

```
$('#myDiv').css('width')
```

Comment: That appears to calculate the width of the element as opposed to what's been set in the class.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Try

```
$('#myDiv').width()
```

Comment: That appears to calculate the width of the element as opposed to what's been set in the class.